# Convert from Type to TypeBuilder

Tags: c#, types, reflection.emit, typebuilder

I'm creating a class on runtime and some of the types are already created inside the ModuleBuilder and I would like to reused them, but I only have the Type and not the TypeBuilder (Which is what I need in order to change it)

Is there a way to convert from Type to TypeBuilder?

```
Type moduleType = ModuleBuilder.GetType(inXmlTemplateProperty.PropertyName);
        if (moduleType == null)
        {
            TypeBuilder newClass = ModuleBuilder.DefineType(inXmlTemplateProperty.PropertyName,
                                                            TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Serializable);

            newClass.SetClassAttributes(inXmlTemplateProperty);

            return newClass;
        }

        return (TypeBuilder)moduleType;
```

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeBuilder is a derived type of Type (via intermediate class TypeInfo).

So you can cast a TypeBuilder into a Type. But not the other way around.

You need to use the highest common level of abstraction (Type).

Do not cast moduleType into a TypeBuilder. 
Later on, you will be able to check if the type has been already created or not, using code like that :

```
class Program
{
    private static Type GetSomeTypePending(string typeName)
    {
        AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("toto.dll"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("toto.dll");
        TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(typeName);
        return tb;
    }

    private static Type GetSomeTypeCreated(string typeName)
    {
        AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("toto.dll"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("toto.dll");
        TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(typeName);
        tb.CreateType(); // do not return the created type, 
        return tb;       // return the typebuilder
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type foo = GetSomeTypePending("tutu");
        Type foo2 = GetSomeTypeCreated("tutu");
        if (IsPendingTypeBuilder(foo))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("foo not yet created");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("foo created");
        }
        if (IsPendingTypeBuilder(foo2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("foo2 not yet created");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("foo2 created");
        }
    }

    private static bool IsPendingTypeBuilder(Type foo)
    {
        return (foo is TypeBuilder) && !((foo as TypeBuilder).IsCreated());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, that was my first attempt, but sadly that throws a InvalidCastException.

Answer (score 0):

> some of the types are already created inside the ModuleBuilder and I would like to reuse them

You can't. As soon as you call `TypeBuilder.CreateType`, the type becomes frozen. Even if you could get access to the `TypeBuilder`, you wouldn't be able to modify the type.