# Get TypeBuilder from defined type in an AssemblyBuilder

Tags: c#, reflection, types

Based on the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675588/convert-from-type-to-typebuilder), a `Type` cannot be converted into a `TypeBuilder`.

However, we have a [method that returns a `AssemblyBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.itypelibconverter.converttypelibtoassembly?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_ITypeLibConverter_ConvertTypeLibToAssembly_System_Object_System_String_System_Int32_System_Runtime_InteropServices_ITypeLibImporterNotifySink_System_Byte___System_Reflection_StrongNameKeyPair_System_Boolean_). It already has types built and defined. We can know that some types might not be correctly converted, however, there is no direct method to get to the `TypeBuilder` and manually fix the issues.

It seems to me very strange to be returning an `AssemblyBuilder` and not provide a method to revise the constructed objects before finalizing it into an `Assembly`, so maybe I'm missing something.

So, Is there a way where we can take a defined type from a `AssemblyBuilder` and either revise it or replace it outright?